# Can I improve my setup in AWS for running (machine learning) python scripts in a container when a file is uploaded to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a working setup in AWS that looks something like:

The point is that whenever a file is uploaded to S3, it will trigger a lambda that will trigger a Codebuild project. The codebuild project is then based on a docker image (Stored at ECR) and needs to run a few bash command, mainly executing python files in the docker image. That works really well actually.

The files in S3 are updated approximately once a day and each execution in codebuild takes around 4 minutes.

I got the question why I am not using fargate/SageMaker (the scripts are basicly machine learning retraining and predictions). I was just thinking about if there would be any advantages in using Fargate and/or SageMaker for this? Is it e.g. possible to use Fargate and execute bash commands inside the container when triggered?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You're wondering the diffenerce between `CodeBuild` and `Fargate`/`SageMaker`

**Price**

Calcute the price of these three products using the links below.

[Pricing Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/fargate/pricing/)

[Pricing SageMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/sagemaker/pricing/)

[Pricing CodeBuild](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/codebuild/pricing/)

As your said, you're using the docker image as the main training tools, so maybe the `Fargate`is more suitable for your scenario.